# Is there a way to change and hide the RSS Feed permalink?

Tags: rss

Right now my RSS Feed is at /feed/. It redirects to Feedburner fine.

What I would to is change the /feed/ link to something only I knew that I could share directly with Feedburner.

1- I still need to have an RSS feed.
2- I need to change its permalink.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this article: https://digwp.com/2012/10/customizing-wordpress-feeds/ for details on how WP does feeds.

Scroll down to the "Customizing feeds with filters and hooks" section for a list of hooks to use for various functions. Lots of good info in that article.

Once you figure out what you want to modify, place the appropriate functions in your Child Theme's `functions.php` file. (It is not recommended to modify your theme's `function.php` file, as any changes you make will get overwritten on the next theme update.)

Comment: That is a good article, however it didn't answer my question. I need a way to change the base root of where the feed path is. Move /feed/ to /feedsecret/.

Comment: One way to change where the feed goes is via a rule in htaccess. This site has tons of info on htaccess: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ . Another resource for htaccess http://www.htaccess-guide.com/ . The feed URL is built into the WP core; this info might help: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds . And the feed URL is derived from the bloginfo() function; see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/ . Dig into the code for bloginfo() to see how the feed URL is 'built'. Caution with modifying core files, not recommended.

Comment: Creating a Custom feed was part of the solution. Instead of trying to change the feed path I decided to: 1- Disable the main RSS feed via plugin 2- Use the WP Custom Post RSS Feed plugin to generate an alternate path. ** This seems to be working. Thanks.

Comment: I posted a summary of the solution here: https://medium.com/@CriticalMAS/how-to-change-your-default-rss-path-in-wordpress-without-touching-code-e7fa9add86b5